# apache LocationMatch

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, httpd.conf, locationmatch

Apache question:
I have a wordpress website.
I want to protect with password the wp login screen.
I don't wanty to allow local .htaccess.
In the virtual host i'm using:

`<LocationMatch "(/wp-admin/|/wp-login.php)">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>`

which works, but i still able to access the login screen via the page id of wordpress: `https://my.domain.com/?page_id=54`
and could find the right syntax for the LocationMatch directive.

It works with `<LocationMatch ".*">` of course but nothing else works, not with even `<LocationMatch ".*54$">`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another LocationMatch directive (Apache 2.4):

`<LocationMatch ".*">
                <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /page_id=54/">
                        AuthType Basic
                        AuthName "Restricted Content"
                        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                        Require valid-user
               </If>
        </LocationMatch>`

[ https://serverfault.com/questions/848320/can-locationmatch-regex-match-query-string-portion ]